# Analytic caustics for 3D objects

Tags: geometry, physics, 3d

Is it possible to efficiently calculate [caustics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caustic_%28optics%29) for a given 3D object, like a torus, or a cube?

To be more precise: let's assume that we have a 3d torus, resting on a 2d plane and a single light source, emitting light in all directions. Is there an "efficient" (polynomial) algorithm for computing the intensity of light at arbitrary point on the plane?

Comment: try: http://physics.stackexchange.com ?  or http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: My guess this has to be discussed in some book about ray tracing. One approximate method is photon mapping http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon_mapping I guess that exact solution can be found only in few cases.